# Why execution doesn't stop when DialogFragment is instantiated?

Tags: android

Why execution doesn't stop when `DialogFragment` is shown?

```
public void someMethod() {
    methodeOne();
    new FeedbackAlertDialog().show(getFragmentManager(), "tag"); // DialogFragment opened
    methodeTwo(); // Looking in logs this is executed when DialogFragment is shown
}
```

Usually execution stops when some other is not finished yet. Can you explain please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why execution doesn't stop when DialogFragment is shown?

`show()` is an asynchronous call. The dialog is not even on the screen by the time `methodeTwo()` is called.

Comment: How to check if a method is async or sync?

Comment: @silk: Just about everything that affects the UI is asynchronous.

Comment: thanks... that's why I'm reading your books, everything is clear :)

Comment: @silk: I will try to add more material in the chapter on dialogs, emphasizing that they are asynchronous. I know that some GUI toolkits use blocking dialogs, but most do not, and Android avoids blocking UI calls wherever possible.